# Apostrophes converting to &#39; in Coldfusion Excel Export

Tags: excel, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Some apostrophes/single quotes in my output are converting to `&#39;`. I don't know why some do and some don't. Is there a way to universally make sure that this character, and other non-alphanumeric, don't convert to ASCII?

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="yes" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="filename=#filename#.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel" />
<cfoutput>#TheReport.Data#</cfoutput>
```

Update: A sample of the output itself

```
<cfset delimiter = Chr(9) />
<cfset new_line = Chr(13) & Chr(10) />
<cfoutput query="report">
  <cfset output = output & "#id##delimiter##first_name##delimiter##last_name#">
  <cfset output = output & new_line />
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: How this relates to Excel?

Comment: If you remove the cfheader and cfcontent (and view source to see the actual content), does the problem go away?

Comment: They do not go away viewing browser source.

Comment: More troubleshooting hints.  If you use cfspreadsheet to create the document first, does the problem go away?  What about if you create it first and then open it directly with Excel?

Comment: I cant tell what your variable #theReport.data# is actually made of, but in a few of my projects, I left the approach of creating excel spreadsheets the way you have listed above and moved to cfspreadsheet.  I had much better success.

Comment: @DanBracuk, We only have CF8.

Comment: @steve, I will post a sample of the output.

Comment: When we only had cf7, we used the apache poi to create real spreadsheets.  Do you either have it or know where to get it?

Comment: _"They do not go away viewing browser source"_ - then they are in the original `TheReport.Data` variable; and thus nothing to do with the code you've posted.

Comment: As Peter pointed out, the problem is in the data, so replace the curly quotes with the normal one and be on your way.

Comment: @Busches, if you are wondering who flagged your comment and why, it was me.  The phrase, "be on your way" is impolite.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Hm.. I did not take it that way. I interpreted his remark as saying "Do `X` and problem solved, you can move on to the next thing".

Comment: 10 points to Gryffindor, erm. @PeterBoughton. That did the trick. Do you want to post your response as an answer for full points, or no?

Comment: \*shrug\* not much of an answer, but there it is...

Comment: You can't flag Busches, I'm the tactless misunderstood one around here... That's my turf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the cfheader and cfcontent (and view source to see the actual content), does the problem go away?

If not, then the encoded quotes are in the original `TheReport.Data` variable, and not related to outputting as an application/msexcel file.

Comment: `#Replace()#` did the trick, since the source itself was ASCII. Not sure why, but that's another matter entirely.